# how to extend ErrorList Windows With Visual Studio 2010 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2010 SDK from Microsoft for creating a visual studio extension. I want to extend Error List Windows for my extension. I have searched a lot on internet and found nothing there.

Is there any way to extend Error List Windows with Visual Studio 2010 Extensions.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Jalpesh

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of how to modify the "Find-in-Files" window as far as visuals.
http://blog.ninlabs.com/2010/12/customizing-visual-studio-search-results/

Otherwise, if you're mainly looking to access the textual contents, you'd be able to access the elements of the error list through the the ErrorListProvider interface.  See this thread: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/a1d37fdf-09e0-41f9-a045-52a8109b8943/